# Turn off scrolling for a UIScrollView but keep zooming functionality

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` and I want to turn off scrolling but I also want to keep the zooming functionality.

When I make `scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO` , it turns off scrolling but zooming is also gone.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says:

> When scrolling is disabled, the scroll view does not accept touch
>   events; it forwards them up the responder chain.

You could try to set the `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize` to it's `bounds` to effectively disable scrolling?